# Clearing the screen by printing a character?

Tags: terminal, scheme, ascii

I'm using chez-scheme and I can't find a way to clear the screen completely. (If someone knows a better way than printing I'd be interested in that too but it's not my question here)

From what I can find clearing the screen by ^L (control-L) or giving the `clear` command (in bash at least) is equivalent to outputting ASCII character 12: `Form feed`.
However, printing this does nothing. If I use `(display (integer->char 12))` it just prints a `newline`. Another way to encode this character is `\f` (analogous to `\n` for `newline`), but in Python `print("\f")` as well as in Scheme `(display "\f")` is just a `newline`.

Is my understanding of the meaning of ASCII 12 just wrong, or are implementations lacking?

Is there any way to clear the screen that should work across languages, analogous to `\n` for a `newline`?

Comment: Your basic understanding is correct but the available functionality depends on the precise output system calls used by the Scheme implementation as well as the terminal environment etc.

Comment: The "terminal environment" caveat is critical. The environment variable TERM tells applications which terminal is in use; to be well behaved and portable, they should look up the operation they want to perform in the termcap/terminfo database for that terminal type, rather than hardcoding an escape sequence.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you want to *clear* the screen, the "ANSI" sequence in a `printf`

```
\033[2J
```

clears the entire screen, e.g.,

```
printf '\033[2J'
```

The command-line [`clear`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/clear.1.html) program uses this, along with moving the cursor to the "home" position, again an "ANSI" sequence:

```
\033[H
```

The program gets the information from the terminal database.  For example, for [`TERM=vt100`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-vt100), it might see this (using `\E` as `\033`):

```
clear=\E[H\E[J$<50>
```

(the `$<50>` indicates *padding* needed for real VT100s).  You might notice that the `2` is absent from this string.  That is because the cursor is *first* moved to the home (upper left) position, and the `2` (entire screen) is not necessary.  Eliminating that from the string made VT100s a *little* faster.

On the other hand, if you just want to ***reset*** the terminal, you can use the [VT100-style `RIS`](http://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html#RIS):

```
\033c
```

but that has side-effects, besides not being in ECMA-48.  These bug reports were for *side-effects* of `\033c`:

- [Debian Bug report logs - #60377
  "reset" broken for dumb terminals](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=60377)
- [Debian Bug report logs - #239205
  "reset changes a unicode console to non-unicode"](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=239205)

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the screen clear when I type control/L?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_form_feed)
- [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)

```
CSI Ps J  Erase in Display (ED).
            Ps = 0  -> Erase Below (default).
            Ps = 1  -> Erase Above.
            Ps = 2  -> Erase All.
            Ps = 3  -> Erase Saved Lines (xterm).
```

- [ECMA-48: Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)

Answer (score 7):

You can print `\033c` which resets the terminal:

```
petite -q <<< '(display "\033c")'
```

`\033` is escape and `c` is literal c.

I can't give you any information about how widely this is supported.

Comment: What does 033 actually refer to?

Comment: @Darklightus `\033` is an octal escape sequence for escape, see the ascii table for reference: `man ascii`

Comment: It's not different shells you need to test against, but different terminals. The shell has no role in interpreting terminal directives.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not familiar with qsh -- does it claim to be POSIX compliant? Were you using printf?

Comment: Based on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISeries_QSHELL) it is based on POSIX and X/Open standards

Answer (score 1):

For C# and JavaScript (and many others), you have to use `\x1b` instead of `\033` as follows:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("\x1b[2J\x1b[H"); // C#
```

```js
console.log("\x1b[2J\x1b[H"); // Node.JS
```

Keep in mind that some poorly implemented pseudoterminals will break if you do this.